# Multiple datasources with same repositories and entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a current requirement of allowing multiple data sources for the same repositories/entities in spring boot using jpa.

What I've managed to find was always related to multiple datasources, with multiple repositories/entites.

However, here I would like to have the same repositories and entities (ie same database structure) for multiple datasources.

And based on same property, programmatically activate a specific datasource.

I've tried the setup demo'ed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

And in both configurations use the same package in the `factoryBean.setPackagesToScan()` call. This does now work however, one datasource overrides the other.

My current test can be found here: https://github.com/nWidart/spring-data-multi-datasource/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/multidatasources

It shows the 2 configuration files (client1 and client2) with a repository and entity. The controller has 2 endpoints for both data sources (not working).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like below :

[image]

 1. application.properties (as default) : as you see, you can switch between datasource files.
 [image]
 
 2. application-test.properties (sample)
 [image]

I hope this can help you. :D

Comment: additinal for you. In big project, file application properties not save in project. It have infomation connect to database and not security. You should be use spring cloud config in here `https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html`

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm looking to do this in one single data source. I came across this blog post which come close: https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/