# Multiple Datasources in Spring Boot using same repository and entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to figure out how to insert the exact same data into two different databases with the same schema. I found this [Multiple datasources with same repositories and entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307851/multiple-datasources-with-same-repositories-and-entities) but it didnt really answer the question.

Say I have a user who is registering and I want to save this user to both databases. How do I do I configure this in spring boot? I have seen different repos/databases but what I want is to use the same repo/entity. I know replication is a thing in databases already but I want to do this on the application level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you are searching is well discussed [in this artiche](https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-databases-with-shared-entity-classes-in-s) with the save action [here](https://github.com/gabrieljeremiahcampbell/multipledatabases/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gabriel/multipledatabaseconnection/controller/MultipleDatabaseController.java)

Just a couple of notes... You can configure two database and you can also set the same entities, but you cannot point at the same repository because each repository is related to a specific `dataSource` and `transactionManager`. Moreover, if you want to have the same entity `ids` across two databases you have to manage them manually.

Comment: Thanks, the article you posted helped.